# Ridge Regression always returns Error

Tags: r, statistics, regression, tweedie

I am attempting to run a ridge regression for a Tweedie distribution using the `HDtweedie` package.  I have no problem whatsoever running elastic net with any level of alpha, except for 0.  When I try to run ridge, it always outputs:

> Error in if (any(lambda < 0)) stop("lambdas should be non-negative") :
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Example using the `auto` package included in `HDTweedie`:

```
require(HDtweedie)
data('auto')
ridge = cv.HDtweedie(auto$x, auto$y, p = 1.44, alpha = 0)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try with a small alpha: `alpha = 1e-20`. It works.

Comment: I tried that and noticed it works, but does anything close enough to 0 function similarly to ridge for all intents and purposes?

Comment: Make a try using `library(glmnet)`: `ridge = cv.glmnet(auto$x, auto$y, alpha = 0)`. It works. I don't know why `HDTweedie` has problem with `alpha=0`

Comment: @J. Gursky: I think a negligibly small alpha will be materially the same as fitting a ridge regression: the alpha term determines the weighting of the ridge regression penalty vs. the LASSO penalty in the loss function (i.e., the bit that encourages small coefficients), and if you're model gives the ridge regression penalty 99.99999999% of the weight then it's functionally just a ridge regression.

Comment: @Marco Sandri, I thought about using `glmnet`, but from my understanding it does not have functionality for Tweedie distributions, does it?

Comment: @J.Gursky You are right. Tweedie distributions are not available inside `glmnet`. In my opinion you can safely use `HDTweedie` with a small alpha.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As @Marco Sandri commented, the easiest way to achieve this is with vanishingly small value of alpha. However a side effect of this is with the choice of lambdas. The default starting value of lambda is described in the HDtweedie docs :

> max(lambda) is the smallest value of lambda for which all coefficients are zero.

If the lasso weight is 1e-20, then this value will be of order 1e+20 to compensate, and as a result the ridge shrinkage effect will be enormous. For me this showed up as vanishingly small coefficients, with the intercept unaffected.

This can be solved by supplying an appropriate set of lambda values by hand.